# How can I animate the model in Three.js fiber?

Tags: javascript

I have a model that I made and animated in blender, through gltfjsx I did all the steps to make the model displayed in the browser. How to make so that all the animations that I have 10 run?

Code:

```
    import React, {useEffect, useRef} from 'react'
    import { useGLTF, useAnimations } from '@react-three/drei'

    export function Model(props) {
    const group = useRef()
    const { nodes, materials, animations } = useGLTF('/cube.glb')
    const { actions } = useAnimations(animations, group)

    return (
    <group ref={group} {...props} dispose={null}>
      <group name="Scene">
        <mesh name="a" geometry={nodes.a.geometry} material={materials['ma']} position={[-16.68,      10.91, 1.38]} rotation={[-0.21, 0.81, 0.26]} />
        <mesh name="b" geometry={nodes.b.geometry} material={materials['mb']} position={[-16.76, 10.56, -0.04]} rotation={[1.57, 0.17, 2.31]} scale={[0.6, 1, 1]} />
        <mesh name="c" geometry={nodes.c.geometry} material={materials['mc']} position={[-15.24, 10.85, 1.28]} rotation={[1.57, 0.19, -2.4]} scale={[0.6, 1, 1]} />
        <mesh name="d" geometry={nodes.d.geometry} material={materials['md']} position={[-18.01, 10.34, 1.56]} rotation={[1.54, 0.17, 0.74]} scale={[0.6, 1, 1]} />
        <mesh name="e" geometry={nodes.e.geometry} material={materials['me']} position={[-16.49, 10.64, 2.8]} rotation={[1.54, 0.2, -0.82]} scale={[0.6, 1, 1]} />
        <mesh name="f" geometry={nodes.f.geometry} material={materials['mf']} position={[-16.77, 10.6, 1.44]} rotation={[1.57, 0.17, -0.83]} scale={[0.05, 0.32, 0.32]} />
        <mesh name="g" geometry={nodes.g.geometry} material={materials['mg']} position={[-16.74, 10.58, 1.48]} rotation={[1.57, 0.17, -0.83]} scale={[0.07, 0.32, 0.32]} />
        <mesh name="h" geometry={nodes.h.geometry} material={materials['mh']} position={[-16.75, 10.58, 1.49]} rotation={[1.57, 0.17, -0.83]} scale={[0.03, 0.32, 0.32]} />
        <mesh name="i" geometry={nodes.i.geometry} material={materials['mi']} position={[-16.66, 10.62, 1.49]} rotation={[1.57, 0.17, -0.83]} scale={[0.02, 0.32, 0.32]} />
        <mesh name="j" geometry={nodes.j.geometry} material={materials['mj']} position={[-16.65, 10.64, 1.38]} rotation={[1.57, 0.17, -0.83]} scale={[0.02, 0.32, 0.32]} />
      </group>
    </group>
    )
  }

useGLTF.preload('/cube.glb')
```

I checked that they are loaded through useEffect, the names that I put in the blender are displayed if I put animations[i].name but according to the guide, which I looked, I can not do the following:
`useEffect(() => { actions.name.play() })`
It gives me an error. Help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To play all `animations` in your model, you can loop through the `actions` object and call the `play()` function on each action.

Here's how you can modify your `Model` component to play all animations:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { useGLTF, useAnimations } from '@react-three/drei';

export function Model(props) {
  const group = useRef();
  const { nodes, materials, animations } = useGLTF('/cube.glb');
  const { actions } = useAnimations(animations, group);

  useEffect(() => {
    for (const actionName in actions) {
      actions[actionName].play();
    }
  }, [actions]);

  // ... rest of the code
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now i have another problem, They are in loop how can i make they disposable on click